# gradle execute a task twice with different property values

Tags: gradle, task

How to execute a task twice with different property values? e.g.

```
project.ext {
   value = 1;
}

task foo {
    doFirst {

       if (value == 1)
           // do something
       else
           // do something else
    }

}
```

Add a new task to execute the task twice with different values:

```
task fooValues {
    project.ext.set("value", 1)
    foo.execute()

    project.ext.set("value", 2)
    foo.execute()
}
```

Error:

```
   task.execute() is deprecated.
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: Why don't you create two tasks, each one of them doing only one thing and then decide which one to skip depending on the property?

Answer (score -1):

The way Gradle works, you would declare two tasks, each doing its own thing and then call them according to your needs.

Or you could even generate the two tasks based on that property value with a Task rule. See [examples](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:task_rules) in the documentation.